# How to delete the latest row of my mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql

So basically I have a program that allows me to insert data in Mysql database through jtextfields and display those data's in a jtextarea.

My problem is I want to delete the latest data I inserted when I click a button in my GUI. but I can't seem to find a good solution.

i have Sales table with Product name , price ,qty, and total sales.

```
    public void deleteRow() {
    actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
try {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/computer_inventory","root",""); 
        PreparedStatement pstate = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM sales WHERE ProductName=(SELECT MAX(ProductName) FROM sales)");

         pstate.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Deleted"); 

                con.close();

}catch(SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");   
}                           
        }

};       
view.deleteData().addActionListener(actionListener);   
    }     }
```

i have further edited the code and above is my new statement, the problem is im receiving an exception and its not deleting a row.

Comment: `delete from your_table order by primary_key_column desc limit 1`

Comment: what constitutes a good solution?

Comment: not aadding a new problem from a solution i think is a good solution.. because i tried a solution from the internet earlier it does delete my row, but the problem is it deleted the whole data

Comment: @SeQuoia what was the solution you used from internet ? Please edit your question to add those previous attempt details as well.

Comment: i added my current delete row statement .

Comment: @SeQuoia, take id as primarykey and autoincrement, then delete from your_table where id=(select max(id) from your_table) Thank you

Comment: Table 'sales' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data  .. for my ("DELETE FROM sales WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM sales)"); code

Comment: ah nevermind my program is working. i will post the answer below . thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/computer_inventory","root",""); 
        PreparedStatement pstate = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM sales WHERE id=(select * from (SELECT  MAX(id) FROM sales)as t)");

         pstate.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Deleted");
```